# How to assign value in a RoR object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a order object, which have a create method like this :

```
 def create
    @order                           = Order.new(params[:order])
    # @order.status_id = "1"

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        flash[:notice]               = 'Order was successfully created.'
        format.html { redirect_to(@order) }
        format.xml  { render :xml    => @order, :status => :created, :location => @order }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml    => @order.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I want to set the @order status_id to "1", so I have the

```
 @order.status_id = "1"
```

But this code is not work, after I uncomment it, it still can't save "1" in the status_id in db, but other attribute can successfully store.

order.rb

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_items
  belongs_to :status

end
```

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Does the new order get saved in the database but its status is not set to 1? Can you post the code for your model?

Comment: We might need to see the model, too.  Is status_id a foreign key?  What happens when you set it to an integer (1) instead of a string ("1")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to assign a string value to a relationship key and it will be converted as required. The params always come in as strings, so obviously this needs to occur for anything to be working.

This is the kind of situation where a robust unit test would help narrow down the scope of the problem. It may be one of:

- There is an attr_accessor defined for status_id that is blocking the assignment.
- There is a status_id= method defined which is blocking the assignment.
- The status_id is being reset during a before_validation or before_save call.

You'd want to create a test routine that verifies this works:

```
def test_status_assignment
  order = Order.new

  order.status_id = '1'

  order.save

  assert_equal 1, order.status_id
end
```

Comment: Good explanation of why assigning string values must work and for suggestion to use a unit test. I would update the test to re-retrieve the record from the database before doing the assert so that the comparison is definitely being done with the persisted value.

Answer (score 1):

You could have `attr_accessible` in your model blocking you from assigning to that field. It does this by using a whitelist of approved fields.

Comment: I don't think it can be this as attr_accessible and attr_protected only affect setting attributes via mass-assignment such as new(attributes), update_attributes(attributes) or attributes=(attributes). So setting status_id specifically via status_id= should be OK

Answer (score 1):

Change `@order.status_id = "1"` to `@order.status_id = 1`

Ruby may be reading `"1"` as a string (which it is supposed to do) instead of an integer (what you are probably looking for). When you remove the quotes ruby will interpret it as an integer. If you must leave it as a string, try something like `my_string.to_i` or `"123".to_i`.

If this doesn't work, please post whatever error message you are receiving.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
@order.status_id = "1"
```

should be

```
@order.status_id = 1
```

Or maybe

```
@order.status = Status.find_by_id(1)
```

if you have relationships set up nicely